# Creating a low cost raspberry lora node

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, lora, tutorial

I'm trying to integrate LORA communication in a project that uses a raspberry pi.

I've bought this module to serve as a gateway for testing: https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B076T28KWG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

My problem is in finding a low cost solution for the raspberry pi so that it can send messages through LORA. I want to deploy multiple raspberry pi so I want to keep costs low on the lora add-on for the raspberry.

Option1: Are there any ready to use raspberry pi lora hats that cost less than 15 euros in Europe?

Option2: Are there any tutorials for connecting lora chips to the raspberry, that are beginner friendly and that clearly explain what the pinout should be to connect the raspberry pi and lora module and what libraries to then use to send the messages?

Also, should i be careful with compatibility between different boards?

I found [this](https://github.com/hallard/LoRasPI) github repository with instructions on how to connect an RFM92/95/96/98/69HCW Module to a raspberry pi. My concerns are that it is 4 years old, so there may be better modules today at a similar price. Also, I'm concerned that the modules may not be compatible with my gateway. Finally, the tutorial may not be simple enough for me to succeed.

Does anyone know of a better or perhaps simpler tutorials/github projects that'll allow me to do this?

For context:
I've got some experience with soldering, but really basic knowledge of electronics theory, so I can't really understand what components in a schematic do.
I have fairly good knowledge on developing software with C/Java/Python/... but I don't usually work with low level code as is the case here.

Comment: Stack exchange sites are very distinct from other parts of the Internet, here questions must be singular and specific, and asking for purchase recommendations and tutorial recommendations is prohibited.  It seems like you need to start with some more study of the subject - for example, figure out if you are going to use LoRaWAN, or some other scheme on top of the raw LoRa.  Beware that the device you linked is not really a "gateway" in the LoRaWAN meaning of the word.  And consider if a pi really suits your node role - do you have mains power at the node?  If not, don't use a pi.

Comment: A lawnmower doesn't need a V8 engine; why not use an MCU instead of a Pi? They draw much less power, boot instantly, and cost a fraction of the price. There's also tons of LORA libs for about every micro you can imagine.

Comment: @dandavis I run image analysis (AI) on the nodes, hence the need for raspberry pi. I've been messing around with a k210 maix go, but it is a lot harder to code than the raspberry, due to a lack of documentation and RAM capacity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton see above. If someone could point me to libraries for using lora with the k210 I might try that instead. I would also like to have the ability to have remote access for maintenance(e.g. without having to physically be in contact with the node), which would also be much harder with the k210.

Comment: You seem to have ignored all but one of the many things I said, especially the parts about how it's too unclear what you are trying to do with LoRa and how even if it were not questions of this sort are fundamentally prohibited here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for the replies, and I'm sorry if the question does not follow the websites guidelines, could you point me at a more appropriate forum?
Regarding the other observations, I understand Lora is a physical layer, while LORAWan is the "logical " layer that runs on top of it. Since LORAWan seems to have a good user  base and hence more support, I'm pretty sure that's what I'll be using. I'm also fairly certain that the linked device supports it. Finally, it is true that power access is also a concern and because of that I might end up using k210, but I'll run some tests first.

Comment: If you want to use LoRaWAN then you really need to get an actual LoRaWAN gateway, what you bought was a LoRaWAN *node*, but it's unclear if LoRaWAN or even LoRa with some other protocol scheme will really suit your purposes - these are very limited pipes and LoRaWAN is "uplink mostly".  There is plenty of online information on both - things like the Things Network (where you may discover why this technology might not fit your need), module manufacturer sites, etc.